# Display the date in textbox powershell forms

Tags: forms, powershell

I am writing a script to get the data from user input as date, when I select another date it is not displaying in text box, please suggest where is the issue

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,600)
$Form.Text = "test"
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"

$TextBoxlabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TextBoxlabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50)
$TextBoxlabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$TextBoxlabel.Text = 'Input No:'
$form.Controls.Add($TextBoxlabel)

$TextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$TextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,50) 
$TextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20) 
$TextBox.MultiLine = $false
$TextBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
$Form.Controls.Add($TextBox)

$StartDatelabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$StartDatelabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,100)
$StartDatelabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$StartDatelabel.Text = 'Start Date:'
$form.Controls.Add($StartDatelabel)

$StartDateTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$StartDateTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,100) 
$StartDateTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20) 
$StartDateTextBox.MultiLine = $false
$StartDateTextBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$Form.Controls.Add($StartDateTextBox)

$Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,100) 
$Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20) 
$Button1.Text = "Date1"

$Button1.Add_Click({

$StartDateInput = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
$StartDateInput.ShowTodayCircle = $false
$StartDateInput.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$StartDateInput.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,120)
$StartDateTextBox.Text = $StartDateInput.SelectionStart
$form.Controls.Add($StartDateInput)
})

$Form.Controls.Add($Button1)
$OutputTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$OutputTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,320) 
$OutputTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(760,200) 
$OutputTextBox.MultiLine = $true
$OutputTextBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$OutputTextBox.ReadOnly = $true
$Form.Controls.Add($OutputTextBox)

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

when I am selecting the date (other than default date) it is not displaying in text box

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting the date"?

Comment: when I select other date , ex: 9th May, it should be print the value in textbox

Comment: Oh, if you mean when you select a date on the MonthCalendar control then it sounds like you need to register an event handler for that control that will set the value of the textbox when the date is selected.